# Managing and querying time-based events in Apache AGE graph database

Tags: database, graph-databases, apache-age

I am working with the Apache AGE graph database extension for PostgreSQL, and I have a use case where I need to store and query time-based events. My dataset consists of various events occurring at different timestamps, and I want to efficiently retrieve events that occurred within a specific time range or during a certain period.

For example, let's say I have a graph representing social media posts and their timestamps. I want to be able to query all posts that occurred within the last week or during a specific month.

Here's what I've tried:

- I've created nodes representing posts with a timestamp property.

```
CALL age.cypher('CREATE (p:Post {content: $1, timestamp: $2})', ['This is a post', '2022-11-12T13:24:00Z']);
```

- I attempted to query the posts within a specific date range using the following query:

```
CALL age.cypher('MATCH (p:Post) WHERE datetime(p.timestamp) >= datetime($1) AND datetime(p.timestamp) <= datetime($2) RETURN p', ['2022-11-01T00:00:00Z', '2022-11-30T23:59:59Z']);
```

While this approach seems to work, I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to handle time-based data in a graph database like Apache AGE.

I was expecting the query to return all posts within the specified date range. Although it does return the expected results, I am concerned about the performance and scalability of this approach when dealing with a large number of events.

My questions are:

- What is the best way to model and store time-based events in Apache AGE?
- How can I efficiently query events that occurred within a specific time range or period?
- Are there any best practices or recommendations for handling time-based data in a graph database like Apache AGE?
  Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The custom datatype that Apache AGE uses to store properties for each vertex/edge, an agtype [1], does not currently support datetime objects.  This maybe a case where you want to use the integration with native PostgreSQL and have a traditional SQL table of post IDs and timestamps.  (Just a two column table to support look ups of post IDs related to timestamps of a specific range.)

While you cannot embed SQL directly into a Cypher query in Apache AGE, you could create a User-Defined-Function [2] to make the SQL call to the post-to-timestamp table and fetch the post IDs and return them to the Cypher query.

[1] https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html

[2] https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/advanced/sql_in_cypher.html

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with time-based events in apache age following points should be considered for effective querying

- **date/time** format should be consistent for timestamp properties in all involved nodes.
- Secondly, if a lot of querying (frequent querying) is based on
  timestamp ranges then partition of data by timestamp can help for better performance.

You can also use **BETWEEN** operator within the cypher query to deal with ranges that makes it more convenient to deal with ranges.